# Is it possible to play 2 WebRTC streams simultaneously in a single Activity via a streaming connection in Android

Tags: android, webrtc, janus, janus-gateway

I am planning to get a video stream from Janus VideoRoom connection which will include video and audio in one stream.

Meanwhile i need to get another stream from Janus AudioBridge, which will be only audio.

Then i have to play them in a single screen simultaneously.

Is it possible in Android?

Any help or guidance in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If u need 2 streams coming from different plugins - I believe Multi-Stream is the solution for this. Streaming plugin is there in Janus.
For this use case i am using Videoroom to manage this. There is a a key "OpaqueId" which you can set for each user. Use that to get if you want to show video or audio or both or none from a specific user. Aiming to use this for this of my usecase.